# Creating a pattern array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

This is probably a very simple problem but I'm trying to create an array of patterns and there are some issues.  What I've done is below:

```
Pattern [] aminos = null;
aminos [0] = Pattern.compile("(gct)|(gcc)|(gca)|(gcg)");
aminos [1] = Pattern.compile("(tgt) | (tgc)");
aminos [2] = Pattern.compile("(gat) | (gac)");
```

There are no syntax errors or anything before I try to run it, but when I try to run it breaks at the 2nd line saying "Null pointer access:  the variable aminos can only be null at this location".  How do I create a Pattern array then?  When I neglected to specify null an error appeared asking me to initialise the array, so I'm unsure what to do now.

I guess I could store all the regex patterns in a String Array and then write a small function to form the patterns as needed but it would be more convenient if I could just make a Pattern array.

Thanks for reading guys!

Comment: Your issue is not related with patterns, but with arrays in Java. You must allocate the array before assigning.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one simple approach:

```
Pattern[] aminos = {
    Pattern.compile("(gct)|(gcc)|(gca)|(gcg)"),
    Pattern.compile("(tgt) | (tgc)"),
    Pattern.compile("(gat) | (gac)")
};
```

Alternatively, you could create an array of the right size to start with:

```
Pattern[] aminos = new Pattern[3];
```

That means getting the counting right though - the first version will automatically give you an array of the right size.

Or use a `List<Pattern>` instead (the collection classes are generally more pleasant to work with than arrays):

```
List<Pattern> aminos = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
aminos.add(Pattern.compile("(gct)|(gcc)|(gca)|(gcg)"));
aminos.add(Pattern.compile("(tgt) | (tgc)"));
aminos.add(Pattern.compile("(gat) | (gac)"));
```

Comment: Thanks great response Jon!  I will accept your answer when I can (6 mins)

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize the array with the size it will be. Java doesn't have flexible arrays.

```
Pattern[] aminos = new Pattern[3];
aminos [0] = Pattern.compile("(gct)|(gcc)|(gca)|(gcg)");
aminos [1] = Pattern.compile("(tgt) | (tgc)");
aminos [2] = Pattern.compile("(gat) | (gac)");
```

If you don't know how many `Pattern`s you will have, you can use an `ArrayList` like this:

```
ArrayList<Pattern> aminos = new ArrayList<Pattern>();
aminos.add(Pattern.compile("(gct)|(gcc)|(gca)|(gcg)");
...
```

`ArrayList`s are the flexible version of an array in Java.